# How to build devops script to build and deploy github pages with gulp?

Tags: github, gulp, github-pages, nunjucks, github-actions

I am attempting to build my static nunjucks site by using gulp through github actions. My gulp build task is designed to write the built website to my dist directory which is a submodule, which I then normally cd into and deploy by pushing to a .github.io page. When I translate this script to github actions the files are not actually being saved in the submodule, so when I attempt to cd into the submodule on the github actions script I get an error like this:

```
    fatal: in unpopulated submodule 'dist'
    ##[error]Process completed with exit code 128.
```